# Optional baseURI (location) in DOMParser?

Tags: url, dom, uri, relative-path, domparser

```js
// html data loaded from [http://example.org/some/path]
let htmlSource = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
 ... <a href="relative"></a> ... 
</body></html>`;

const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlSource, 'text/html');

// this returns the value of the attribute as is
dom.links[0].getAttribute('href'); // -> "relative" / nothing new here

// this should resolve urls
dom.links[0].href // -> wait, relative to WHAT??

// if you run this code while being on [http://google.com] you'll get
dom.links[0].href // -> "https://www.google.com/relative"

// Also,

dom.location // -> null / you can't change it

dom.baseURI // -> "https://www.google.com/" / read-only
```

So it looks like `DOMParser` implicitly forces to use current page `location` as `baseURI` for new `HTMLDocument`'s.

Why not give developer an option (3rd argument?) to explicitly specify document location?

Is there a way to make `DOMParser` respect optional base url? Workarounds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use a `base` tag inside the html code, you can even add it dynamically. Here is your example:

```js
const htmlSource = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="https://www.example.com/">
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="relative"></a>
 </body>
</html>`;

const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlSource, 'text/html');
console.log('DOM link ->', dom.links[0].href);
```

Will output:

```
DOM link -> https://www.example.com/relative
```

Add it dynamically:

```
let baseEl = dom.createElement('base');
baseEl.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.example.com');
dom.head.append(baseEl);
```

Comment: Nice. I would add check for base element presence `if (dom.head.getElementsByTagName('base').length == 0)`